# How to vertically align items with flex box direction column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to vertically align these three items so that each section aligns with the same element on the section next to it. Heres an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-fast-53z9y?file=/index.html

Normally when doing something like this i would use align self to choose the position of the flex item in the flex box, But what if i am using flex-direction?

Is there any way to do this or will it involve javascript?

edit: The suggestion does not answer my question

Comment: Why was this closed? The question associated with this is not relevant at all... Its talking about using 'subgrid' which is only supported in firefox

Comment: The point is that `subgrid` is the only way of doing this without javascript.